# Using binded drop downs, value falling through others

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three drop downs, and they all bind to the same data, now I am trying to select the drop down values when the client comes back to the last settings they stored. They will map to the ones in the drop downs. The problem I am having is that whatever value the last drop down is taking.. is defaulting to the other ones although I am setting dropdown 1 with a value, drop down 2 with a value and drop down 3 with a different value... but all are selected to the value of the 3rd drop down.

```
var item1 = ddlMyItem1.Items.FindByValue("1");

            if(item1!=null)
            {
                ddlMyItem1.ClearSelection();
                item1.Selected = true;
            }

            var item2 = ddlMyItem2.Items.FindByValue("2");

            if (item2 != null)
            {
                ddlMyItem2.ClearSelection();
                item2.Selected = true;
            }
            var item3 = ddlMyItem3.Items.FindByValue("3");

            if (item3 != null)
            {
                ddlMyItem3.ClearSelection();
                item3.Selected = true;
            }
```

For all drop downs it is defaulting to the value of the last one.. Any ideas why? or how i can fix this.. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your control declarations in the ASPX file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to your databinding.

I may be off, but if you're databinding like this:

```
foreach(var item in myListItems)
    ddlMyItem1.Items.Add(item)

foreach(var item in myListItems)
    ddlMyItem2.Items.Add(item)

foreach(var item in myListItems)
    ddlMyItem3.Items.Add(item)
```

The reference to each list item is the same for all your drop downs.  Instead of manually building the Items collection; you're better off using the `DataSource` property.  The will create unique references; so something like this:

```
        var list = new ListItemCollection {new ListItem("1", "1"), new ListItem("2", "2"), new ListItem("3", "3")};

        DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        DropDownList2.DataSource = list;
        DropDownList2.DataBind();

        DropDownList3.DataSource = list;
        DropDownList3.DataBind();

        var item = DropDownList3.Items.FindByValue("3");
        item.Selected = true;
```

**EDIT:**

OK; here's what I would do to try and get this cleaned up:

1.)  Create a static method that will return a collection of ListItems.  This is what you're going to bind your DropDownLists to.

2.)  Bind that collection of ListItems to the DataSource of each drop down; and then call DataBind().

3.)  Pre-set each DropDownList with the saved values for the user.

Using an ObjectDataSource is also a valid way to go about this; but the above should get you going in the right direction.  DO NOT add to the DropDownList Items collection; as that's what's getting you into trouble in the first place.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, Yes, I think you are right but I am not sure how to implement that in my existing code.. I am a bit confused.. I wrote the code I have at top

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.. thank you for your advise, I added a new instance for each li and that worked

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code.  We can help you solve your problem, but your foundation is not very solid.

1. Only call your `BindMyItems()` when `Page.IsNotPostback()`
2. Inside `BindMyItems`, bind all 3 DDL to that dataview you have.  After you `.DataBind()` it, then insert your default value using `.InsertAt(0, liDefault)`.
3. The first two steps will always take place; now if you want to load your values that you saved from the database, you create another function called `LoadDDLValues()`
4. Inside `LoadDDLValues()`, you use that load logic you already have (it is fine).  This function should only be called when you load the pages other values (usually it's only loaded once when `Page.IsNotPostback()` or when you refresh the data)